# Matrix based Game Design

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

**Hello there, StackOverflow!**

I am in the process of writing a JavaScript edition of the popular game [Pentago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentago) as a side project before I have to return to classes in the fall.  I am, unfortunately, entirely stumped in regards to how to proceed from my current progress with this project.

**My Approach**

When I began writing this project, I assumed that the best approach for this game would be to instantiate four matrices and put them in a list.  Each matrix would represent one section of the Pentago board. I found that this approach caused me a great deal of headaches when considering my approach to how I would iterate over the matrices and determine whether or not a row of 5 game tokens had been placed.

**Re-evaluation of my approach**

I then decided to get an outside perspective on how I could approach this problem to make it simpler to solve.  What was suggested was that I use one matrix instead of four.  This, however does seem to make rotating each section a bit more difficult, but not unreasonably so.

**My question...**

This having all been said, what I really need to know is how I should approach determining if a player has won the game after having placed a 'token' in a certain position.

Here is what I *think* I know:

- The function that will determine if the game is over will be executed after a player has rotated a quadrant.
- Given this, I will know which player placed that last token.  I will only need to consider tokens placed by that player.
- I must iterate over the matrix from the position in the matrix that the last token was placed from, and determine if a token is adjacent to it.  Then, recursively perform this action on every adjacent token until I have found five adjacent tokens either diagonally, vertically, or horizontally.

What follows is the code that I have already written for this game.  I would really appreciate any help that I can get on this part of the project... it has really stumped me!
Thanks!

**Code so far**

https://github.com/jakenewby/pentagojs/tree/master/www/app

```
var game = (function (players){

    var self = {};
    self.numTokensPlaced = 0;

    // instantiate the pentago board to all empty
    self.board = [];
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        self.board[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j<6; j++) 
        {
          self.board[i][j] = null;
        }
    }

    // rotate one of the four sections of the board
    // given a section and a direction
    self.rotateSection = function (section, direction)
    {
      if(isGameOver())
      {

      }
      else
      {
        if(direction == 'clockwise')
        {
          /*
            var newGrid = [];
            var rowLength = Math.sqrt(section.length);
            newGrid.length = section.length

            for (var i = 0; i < section.length; i++)
            {
                //convert to x/y
                var x = i % rowLength;
                var y = Math.floor(i / rowLength);

                //find new x/y
                var newX = rowLength - y - 1;
                var newY = x;

                //convert back to index
                var newPosition = newY * rowLength + newX;
                newGrid[newPosition] = section[i];
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < newGrid.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(newGrid[i])
            }
            */
        }
        else
        {
          // rotate counter clockwise
        }
        switchTurns();
      }
    }

    // place a token at a place on the board given
    // the player placing the token, the section, and the
    // location coordinates in that section that the token
    // is being placed.
    self.placeToken = function(playerid, location)
    {
        if (self.board[location[0]][location[1]] != null)
        {
            return location.toString() + ' is already taken';
        }
        else
        {
            self.board[location[0]][location[1]] = playerid;
            self.numTokensPlaced = self.numTokensPlaced + 1;
            if(isGameOver())
            {
                alert('game is over!');
            }
        }
    }

    // looks at the current player, and sets the current
    // player variable to the other player to switch turns.
    function switchTurns()
    {
      if (players.current == players[0])
      {
        players.current = players[1];
      }
      else
      {
        players.current = players[0];
      }
      console.log(players.current);
    }

    // look through the board to see if there are any
    // five tokens in a row belonging to one player.
    // returns bool
    function isGameOver(consecutiveTokens)
    {
      // game cannot be over if the number
      // of tokens placed is less than 10
        if(self.numTokensPlaced() >= 10)
        {
            if(consecutiveTokens < 5)
            {
                for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if(self.board[i] != null)
                    {
                        for(j=0; j < 3; j++)
                        {
                            if(self.board[i][j] != null)
                            { 
                                if(self.board[i][j] == players.current)
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;   
            }
        }      
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return self;
}());
```

**Rules of the game.**

Place a marble in a quadrant.  After placing your marble in one of the quadrants, rotate  one of the quadrants 90 degrees either direction.  After aligning five marbles either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, you win!

[image]

Comment: Please post a relevant snippet of your code here. I doubt the github link will break anytime soon, but if you can't pick out a small section of code to focus on, your question may be too broad.

Comment: I would just create an array of 12 functions that traverse each axis to find 5 consecutive balls of a particular colour; once you get a hit, game over ... assuming you don't count diagonal :)

Comment: This post is in regards to the function(s)/method(s) of the game that determine if a player has won after rotating a section of the board.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Jack, It would have to account for diagonals, so... 15 functions.  I will give this implementation some thought.  Thank you for the input!

Comment: Sometimes, framing your question as a puzzle and letting people have at it is a good way to survey approaches and take what you will from their solutions. Then they don't have to second-guess what you consider a giveaway or not. The place for that is [CodeGolf StackExchange](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com); but you have to formalize the inputs and outputs of your puzzle and what the "winning condition" is for those who might show approaches.  Code Golf isn't the only (or necessarily best) winning condition for good methods, but it sometimes reveals ways of thinking that save overall effort.

Comment: Thank you for that, HostileFork!  I was actually looking for somewhere relevant to post this aside from the general boards of StackOverflow.  I assume CodeGolf is a relevant sub-forum for questions like mine?  I will cross-post this to CodeGolf if that is the case.

Comment: SO would be a better place if everyone put half the time into formulating there questions as this poster did.

Comment: Awww, shucks.  Thanks Tommy!  This project is near and dear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a fixed board I would solve it by creating an array of possible axes:

```
var axes = [];

// rows
for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    axes.push(self.board[i]);
}
// columns
for (var j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
    var column = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        column.push(self.board[i][j]);
    }
}
// diagonals
axes.push([self.board[0][1], self.board[1][2], ...])
// two more
```

With that array you can simply traverse all axes and find consecutive fills for a particular player.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it just requires a fresh perspective :)